# Custom date format in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, date-format, custom-formatting, vba

I am trying to use the custom format to change the date from English to French. The custom code in regular Excel is [$-C0C]d mmmm;@ and yields the output as 20 juillet.

When using the following VBA code:

Format(Range("B2"), "[$-C0C]d mmmm;@")

The output is 20 July

[$-C0C] is supposed to be the code for French Canada

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Try this

```
'~~> Replace Sheet1 below with the sheet code name of the cell which has date
Debug.Print Sheet1.Evaluate("text(B2, ""[$-C0C]d mmmm;@"")")
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Explanation**: The format function can only take one of the pre-defined values as mentioned in [Format Function (Visual Basic for Applications)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications). Check out the section `User-Defined Date/Time Formats (Format Function)` And hence we use an alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me:

```
Sheet1.Range("B2").NumberFormat = "[$-C0C]d mmmm;@"
```

Comment: The idea is not to change the cell in Excel :) But get the value in VBA

Comment: BTW no need to create a new answer. You can edit the old one and undelete it

Comment: @SiddharthRout honest question, how did you determine that?

Comment: `Format(Range("B2"), "[$-C0C]d mmmm;@") The output is 20 July` No where OP is assigning the value to the cell. :)

Comment: But hey.. let's wait for OP. You never know he may actually be asking to change the cell in Excel ;)